# unable to create table with spaces in table name dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to create new table with table name from another table's row this is what I did so far

```
<?php
header('content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8');
include "db.php";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from tb1");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$out[] = $row['title'];//see below what it outs
for($i=0;$i<=count($out);$i++)
{
$query = 'CREATE TABLE  '.$out[$i].' (PersonID int,LastName varchar(255),FirstName varchar(255),Address varchar(255),City varchar(255))';
$sqls = mysql_query($query);
}
// if (!$sqls) {
  //die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
//}

?>
```

**$out[] has output like**

```
word one word two word three


Note:its not a single title it has three words
word one-->title one
word two -->title two
word three-->title three
```

Comment: [MySQL "Schema Object Names"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html). Get in the habit of reading the documentation.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I'll Follow it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tablename, column name with space is not recommended, but if really needs to be created with space then it needs to be wrapped in backticks

```
$query = 'CREATE TABLE  `'.$out[$i].'`
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: Great its right,But I like to know more about backticks I didn't find it in keyboard...what is it...

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/254076/how-do-i-type-the-tick-and-backtick-characters-on-windows